# Can I get the javac command equivalent to an Eclipse export to JAR for a project (or NetBeans)?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jar, export

I have the following task at hand: I have a Java project in Eclipse on `machineA` that I need to run on `machineB`. These machines are similar but different and I am getting an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531786/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-after-copying-jars-from-one) trying to run on `B` the JAR that I exported on `A`. So what I want to do it to try rebuilding my code on `B`. Now, a standard way to do that would be to set up the project on `A` as an Ant or Maven build, copy the project to `B` and then run Ant/Maven on `B` from command line (I don't have Eclipse installed on `B`). However, `B` is a bit... "special" in different ways. For instance, its default `java` is 1.6 but it also has a local install of 1.7 that I am using. That install has both `java` and `javac`. There is no Maven there at all and there is a custom Ant install that may not correspond to the java install.

So the question is: is there a way to generate the `javac` command that would be used on `A` to export to JAR, so that I could run that command from the command line, possibly with some mods, to (re)build the project on `B`?

UPDATE: Would it be easier to do the same in Netbeans? If so, I would be willing to give it a try.

Comment: If you don't have maven on MachineB how will you manage dependencies on it ? or are you going to put all the needed Jars in the project ?

Comment: Yes, the latter. There are only a couple of external JARs that I need.

Comment: Try creating an Ant build file for your project, you'll need Ant on MachineB.

Comment: The whole point of my question is that I don't have Ant on `B`

Comment: Then as answered by arcy, you're left with JAR command. In fact you don't even need for 99% of the cases, just use any ZIP tool to zip the content of the project in proper JAR structure and if it's a runnable JAR then make an entry insize MANIFEST. That's all there is too it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the `jar` command, as opposed to a `javac` option. The jar command, part of the Java JDK, creates a jar file for you. There is documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

But this will create the same jar that eclipse will create, so I expect there is some problem running it on your `B` machine that does not have to do, strictly, with creating jar files. So more detail on the problem you're having on B would help.

Comment: Whether it's `javac`, `jar` or a combination of the two, the idea is to copy the source to `B` from `A` and then run those commands on `B` getting a JAR similar to the JAR I would get on `A` by doing an Eclipse export. In which case I suspect the JAR made on `B` should run fine on `B`. In which case I am not sure if the errors I was getting on `B` for the JAR I created on `A` would be relevant, but anyhow, I was getting `Could not find or load main class` as I described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531786/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-after-copying-jars-from-one